# MongoDB summing field of document during query

Tags: mongodb, go

I want to execute a mongodb query that would fetch documents until the sum of a field of those documents exceeds a value. For example, if I have the following documents

```
{id: 1, qty: 40}
{id: 2, qty: 50}
{id: 3, qty: 30}
```

and I have a set quantity of 80, I would want to retrieve id1 and id2 because 40+50 is 90 and is now over 80. If I wanted a quantity of 90, I would also retrieve id1 and id2. Does anyone have any insight into how to query in this manner? (I'm using Go btw - but any general mongo query advice would help tremendously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're keeping a running sum of a certain field, the easiest way of doing this is running a `Find` operation, get a cursor, and iterate the cursor while keeping the sum yourself until the required total is reached. Then, close the cursor and return:

```
cursor, err:=coll.Find(context.Background(),query)
sum:=0
defer cursor.Close(context.Background())
for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
   cursor.Decode(&data)
   sum+=data.Qty
   if sum>=80 {
      break
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to optimize this? Like write a query such that it stops retrieving documents once the sum exceeds some value?

Comment: Cursor will do just that. It will fetch in batches. You cannot really do this with a query.